# sum over list of functions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, summation

I have a Do loop with i running from 1 to 10. Inside that do loop I define functions

```
f[a_,b_,c_]:= F[a,b,c]
```

where the F on the rhs are complicated functions that depend implicitly on the index i. After the loop is finished I thus should have 10 different functions fi. These I need to sum to obtain a new function

```
G[a_,b_,c_]:= Sum[fi[a,b,c],{i,1,10}]
```

How do I do this? I tried to write each function f into a listelement. I can then indeed sum the listelement, but I cannot keep the functional dependence. I tried to do

```
f[[i]][a_,b_,c_]:= F[a,b,c]
```

but that did not work.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your code since Mma reserves the underscore `_` for a different purpose. Have a look into the documentation. Your code should be modified as follows: `f[a_,b_,c_,i_]:= F[a,b,c,i];  G[a_,b_,c_]:= Sum[f[a,b,c,i],{i,1,10}]`. Have fun!

Comment: thanks, I was using latex notation for an index. Trouble with your solution is that I do not know the dependence of F on index i explicitly. Thus, I cannot write F[a,b,c,i].

Comment: `Through[Total[functions][a, b, c]]` ? Also what does it mean to _depend implicitly on the index i_ ? Either they depend on i or they don't.

Comment: `f[[i]][a_, b_, c_] :=  F[a, b, c]` should be `f[i][a_, b_, c_] :=  F[a, b, c]`. `[[ ...]]` is used to take a `Part` of an object such as a `List`.

Comment: g[a_, b_, c_] := Through[(Plus @@ {f1, f2, f3}) @@ {a, b, c}]

Comment: A good idea would be to post your functions. If they are too complex, try to post a minimal example that is simple as much as possible, but catch their main properties.

Comment: @BobHanlon: thanks, this works. Even though I do not understand the notation: what does a function f[i][a] mean? These are clearly not two arguments. Please explain.

Comment: The notation effectively makes `f` an indexed variable (what you appeared to be trying to do when you misused `Part`) and defines `SubValues` of `f`. For example, define `h[1][x_]:=x; h[2][x_]:=x^2; h[3][x_]:=x^3;` then look at `Information[h]` or `??h` Alternatively, you can do what @AlexeiBoulbitch suggested and put the index in with the other arguments.